# flexslider images not centered

Tags: css, flexslider

I'm using javascript/css-based [flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) as an easy way to incorporate a "slide show" into a simple web page.

However the "current" image is not centered within the flexslider div box; and a piece of the "previous" image is still visible to the left of the "current" image ([example of the problem](http://studio-porcelli.com/new/)).

Any thoughts on what I have done incorrectly?

Comment: You should show us the code, you have implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following as options in your slider function :

```
 $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation:"slide",
    controlsContainer: ".flex-container",
    itemWidth: 0,                   //{NEW} Integer: Box-model width of individual carousel items, including horizontal borders and padding.
    itemMargin: 0,                  //{NEW} Integer: Margin between carousel items.
});
```

Change tjhe itemWidth to the container width, i.e : 844px

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

First, apply a css-reset to your site.

The width of content(images) is 844px but the plugin calculates the li width to be 900px. This is because the plugin might also calculate the margin / padding of li which is applied by browser by default. (For testing purpose through firebug just remove 900px width. you will get centered content.)

Thanks.